# converge values to range [-pi,pi] in matlab, NOT using wraptopi

Tags: matlab, pi

The assignment is: **Reset the values stored in the matrix accordingly, so that they lie within this range [-pi,pi]. Take care not to use any non-standard Matlab function(s) to do this.**

(of course are all angles theta + 2n*pi the same, for any integer n. Therefore for example: an angle of 1.5*pi should be reset to -0.5*pi.)

The nonstandard matlabfunction wraptopi does this (I think), but I am not allowed to use this function.
I've got the feeling that I could use modulo to do this, but I don't know how.

Could anyone help me please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Modulo will work.  When you want to wrap onto a range that doesn't start at zero [0... N), you can add an offset, do modulo, then subtract the offset out again.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm almost there. However, when I compare my result with what wraptopi does, my values are on avarage a bit to big...
This is what I did:


%Start off with matrix D

**offset=max(max(D(:,:)));**
% determine the offset: I take the max value of the matrix

**D_with_offset=D+offset;**
% add the offset

**D_mod=mod(D_with_offset,(2*pi));**
% take the modulo of all values, with 2pi

**D_back_within_range=D_mod-pi;**
% remove the offset again

Could someone tell me where this goes wrong?

Comment: Your offset should just be `pi`, not the max of the matrix.  Same value you subtract out at the end.

Answer (score 4):

To expand on @Ben Voight, you could use modulo-style operations this way:

To wrap to [0, 2*pi], you'd do this:

```
angle_rad = angle_rad - 2*pi*floor(angle_rad/(2*pi));
```

To wrap to [-pi, +pi], you'd add another term

```
angle_rad = angle_rad - 2*pi*floor( (angle_rad+pi)/(2*pi) );
```